# Add button to copy text in MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a program that contains a list of names, and a button that displays a random name in a MessageBox. Is there any way I can add a button "Copy" next to the OK to the MessageBox, that when clicked copies the name and then closes?

If the above isn't possible, is there a way to enable copying the text in a MessageBox?

Thank you.

edit: My users won't understand Ctrl+C, Highlight and Right Click > Copy is what I'm looking for (if a Copy button isn't possible)

Comment: I have a vague memory that Windows message boxes support CTRL-C natively. Can't confirm it right now though...

Comment: @FredrikMörk: They do

Comment: Even once you figure out the code part, your next question is going to be how to add a custom button to the MessageBox. That's possible, but not at all easy. You might be better off creating your own message box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If a user presses `Ctrl-C` while the MessageBox has focus, the message, the MessageBox caption and the MessageBoxButtons labels are copied to the clipboard.

I googled your title and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840231/c-sharp-select-text-from-messagebox-show-popup)..

Or if you really need a button that says copy you can create your own `MessageBox` with a new windows form and then do what you want with the buttons. Open it like this to keep the `MessageBox` feel :

```
var myMessageBox = new CustomMessageBox();
myMessageBox.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I want it to be easier for my users to copy text. I'll take a look at that,  but I'm mainly interested if I can add a button to copy the text

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe you are looking for the [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx) class.

```
Clipboard.SetText(variableWithValue);
```

There is also another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545835/replacement-for-yes-no-cancel-messagebox-c) about manipulating the contents of a Message Box.

It also might be easier to simply make a modal dialog that emulates a MessageBox without actually using the MessageBox class.

Comment: Looking into this now.. If I can get something working I'll choose you as best answer.